# Why is deque slower when used in this python code compared to a list with pop(0)

Tags: python, queue, deque

`popleft` with *deque* is supposed to be O(1) and `pop(0)` from a *list* is supposed to be O(n), so why continually when I use a regular list over a queue do I get slower times on leetcode.

Here is both code samples solving a BFS problem on leetcode:

###### Deque:

```py
if not root:
    return root
lev = 0
dummy = Node(0)
prev = dummy

q = deque()
q.append((root, 0))

while q:
    curr = q.popleft()
    print(curr[0].val)
    if curr[1] != lev:
        prev.next = None
        prev = curr[0]
        lev = curr[1]
    else:
        prev.next = curr[0]
        prev = curr[0]
    
    if curr[0].left:
        q.append((curr[0].left, curr[1] + 1))
    if curr[0].right:
        q.append((curr[0].right, curr[1] + 1))


prev.next = None
return dummy.next
```

###### Regular List:

```py
if not root:
    return root
lev = 0
dummy = Node(0)
prev = dummy

q = []
q.append((root, 0))

while q:
    curr = q.pop(0)
    print(curr[0].val)
    if curr[1] != lev:
        prev.next = None
        prev = curr[0]
        lev = curr[1]
    else:
        prev.next = curr[0]
        prev = curr[0]
    
    if curr[0].left:
        q.append((curr[0].left, curr[1] + 1))
    if curr[0].right:
        q.append((curr[0].right, curr[1] + 1))


prev.next = None
return dummy.next
```

The regular list approach beat 30 percent versus 6 percent with *deque*.

Comment: What's the maximum size of the queue? O(N) is meaningless on small N. It could simply be that list has a significantly lower constant overhead.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76756510/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: It looks like you're doing some sort of tree algorithm.  So i gotta agree with @Homer512.  If you've got 100 items or 1000 items, then definitely you need to use a deque.

Comment: @Homer512 doesn't seem to be the case in my small tests. e.g. initialize `d = colletions.deque()` and `l = list()`, then time: `%timeit d.append(1); d.append(2); d.popleft(); d.popleft()` gets `182 ns ± 1.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)` and `%timeit l.append(1); l.append(2); l.pop(0); l.pop(0)` gives `411 ns ± 2.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)`.

Comment: In any case, this code requires a [mcve] ideally with code that actually does the profiling.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. Even test cases where I reuse the list (so that it can reuse its allocations) show a clear advantage for deque. Could be related to the Python version. Mine is 3.11

Comment: @Homer512 I doubt it. My suspicion is that it is not, in fact, slower.